# Vertex-AI is not properly importing my CSV of pre-labelled text data for custom sentiment analysis

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I tried importing a text file (delimited by commas) into the import wizard of Vertex-AI, but the file was uploaded to the Cloud as a single string (i.e., Vertex did not recognize the columns or rows). My file has the following columns, and is encoded in "utf-8".

1. ml_use
2. "in_text"
3. sentiment_score
4. sentiment_max

I am following the Google Cloud Console instructions recorded on this webpage.
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/text-data/sentiment-analysis/create-dataset?hl=en#google-cloud-console

Here is a test file I tried uploading as an example.

```
TRAIN,"my family loves it",0,4
TRAIN,"Long-term repurchased food, tastes good",3,4 
TRAIN,"High quality and low price, fast  logistics.",3,4 
VALIDATION,"Not bad, very good. The price is also ok.",2,4 
TEST,"Good as always, hope to do more activities and more discounts",4,4
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to import the dataset after creating the JSON (alternative to the CSV) and importing the file & dataset using the API. Gotta love the long route.